# How to find a specific xml node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i have this problem to find a particular xml node l have post this problem on stackoverflow and some nice fellows suggested xpath.

I am an xml newbie . please I need an c# code to find the parent , parent, parent as (great grand parent) then the first child ,lastchild , lastchild  . the code have to iterate up the tree and down again. Be looking  at a lot of xpath tutorials online.

I discovered that the path tend to be specific to a particular node already existing . The program that I need  will not get no particular named  node because at each pass a new node will be add to the xml tree.     The long and short of it all is that I need find the node base on it’s position  away from the current node

i meant finding the parent parent parent of a currentnode (great grand parentnode )then find the first child then find the lastchild lastchild

keepkind of  currentnode.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode.firstchild.lastchild.lastchild;

using xpath C#

Comment: Please reformat the question so anyone can read it.

Comment: And please be more specific in the question. I'm really not sure what you want to do. Find the root node of a certain node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that you have an XmlNode instance called `node` to start with. Then the following code will give you the last child of the last child of the first child of the great grand parent of that node:

```
XmlNode wantedNode = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.LastChild.LastChild;
```

Note that there are so many things that can go wrong with this code. If any of the referenced nodes happen to be null, you have a NullReferenceException coming. So you will want to make a null check at each level:

```
XmlNode wantedNode;

if (node.ParentNode != null && node.ParentNode.ParentNode != null /* and so on through the full path */)
{
    wantedNode = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.LastChild.LastChild;
}
```

Let's examine this with a more concrete example. Assume we have the following Xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <greatgrandparent>
    <grandparent>
      <parent id="1">
        <child somevalue="3"></child>
      </parent>
      <parent id="2">
        <child somevalue="4"></child>
        <child somevalue="5"></child>
      </parent>
    </grandparent>
  </greatgrandparent>
</root>
```

If I understand your question right, if we start from the node `<child somevalue="3"></child>` we want to navigate to `<child somevalue="5"></child>`. The code sample above will do that. However, as mentioned, it is prone to giving exceptions if not all expected nodes are present.

Even though you said that you want c# code rather than XPath, in this case I feel that XPath is the way to go. There are a number of ways to solve this. For instance, if the nodes have different tag names (as in my sample document), you can instead do like this:

```
XmlNode wantedNode = node.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::greatgrandparent/grandparent[position()=1]/parent[position()=last()]/child[position()=last()]");
if (wantedNode != null)
{
    // the path was found
}
```

This is of course assuming that `node` is not null, but a valid XmlNode instance.

Breakdown of the XPath expression:

- ancestor::greatgrandparent -> this will locate any node named "greatgrandparent" that is located anywhere upwards in the hierarchy (so any parent, grand parent and so on)
- /grandparent[position()=1] -> the first child node named "grandparent"
- /parent[position()=last()] -> the last child node named "parent"
- /child[position()=last()] -> the last child node named "child"

If you want to read some about how XPath axes work, there is some information on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp).

Comment: hi fredrik that did not work for me i kept getting exception message

Comment: yes dude u readed me right!!! . Thanks a lot one more thing please explain this "ancestor::greatgrandparent/grandparent[position()=1]/parent[position()=last()]/child[position()=last()]");"
ancestor i understood that! what are the rest stand for thank fredrik  u have been a great help

Comment: I added a step by step explanation of the xpath expression in the end.

Answer (score 2):

All the question you are asking are answered by the [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) class. It has properties called `ParentNode`, `FirstChild` and `LastChild` which each return another `XmlNode`.

To do the same thing in XPath you can use the `".."` abbreviation to get a nodes parent, and `"*[position()=1]"` or `"*[position()=last()]"` to get the first and last child, e.g.:

```
XmlNode foundNode = node.SelectSingleNode("../../../*[position()=1]/*[position()=last()]/*[position()=last()]");
```

(Notes: ".." is an abbreviation of the parent::* axis, and "*" is an abbreviation of the "child::*" axis)

Comment: thanks samjudson can u be more Elaborate please .  i think u are hitting the point

Comment: Elaborate how? What do you not understand?